# Why the member wasn't found in my XAML file?

Tags: wpf, xaml, .net-core

I have a XAML file that I want to localize. The following `.resx` files are inside my Properties directory:

- Resources.resx
- Resources.de-DE.resx

The key `mwjobtitle` is defined in both resources files.

I added to XAML:

```
xmlns:p="clr-namespace:latex_curriculum_vitae.Properties"
```

Then I added:

```
<Label Content="{x:Static p:Resources.mwjobtitle}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="64,52,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
```

While writing `p:Resources` the autocomplete finds already the entry `mwjobtitle`, but I'm getting:

```
Fehler  XDG0062 Member 'latex_curriculum_vitae.Properties.Resources.mwjobtitle' not found.  latex_curriculum_vitae  MainWindow.xaml 12
```

So I can't compile it now. What can I do?

The complete project can be found [there](https://github.com/saigkill/latex_curriculum_vitae-dotnet/tree/master/latex_curriculum_vitae).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to access resources in XAML, the access modifer of the `.resx` files must be *Public*. You can open the resource file in Visual Studio, and select *Public* from the access modifier drop-down.

[image: Access Modifier]

Alternatively, right-click the resource file, select *Properties* and set the *Custom Tool* to *PublicResXFileCodeGenerator*.

[image: Properties]